# expand and contract label not working in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to use a UITableView and have cell contents which will expand or contract when the user clicks on the label.

However, the behavior I'm seeing is that the cell will contract (e.g. I am changing the label's numberOfLines from 0 to 1, and then the label will contract). However, when I change the label's numberOfLines from 1 to 0 it doesn't expand.

I put together a simple test program to show the issue I'm having.

I'm using a UITapGestureRecognizer to handle the tap event for the label, and that is where I expand or contract the label.  Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my storyboard and view controller code.

[image]

```
import UIKit

class MyCell : UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
}

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let cellID = "cell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 75

    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 12
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "section " + String(section)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 4
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: self.cellID, for: indexPath) as! MyCell

        cell.myLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleCellTapped(_:)))
        cell.myLabel!.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

        // Configure the cell...
        if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
            cell.myLabel?.numberOfLines = 1
            cell.myLabel.text = "This is some long text that should be truncated.  It should not span over multiple lines. Let's hope this actually works. \(indexPath.row)"
        } else {
            cell.myLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
            cell.myLabel.text = "This is some really, really long text.  It should span over multiple lines. Let's hope this actually works. \(indexPath.row)"
        }

        return cell
    }

    @objc func handleCellTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Inside handleCellTapped...")
        guard let label = (sender.view as? UILabel) else { return }

        //label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // expand or contract the cell accordingly
        if label.numberOfLines == 0 {
            label.numberOfLines = 1
        } else {
            label.numberOfLines = 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try adding tableView.layoutIfNeeded() at the end of handleCellTapped?

Comment: @Karthick Ramesh - It made no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost get it, but here is a couple of things you should care about.

First, handle the `label` by `UIGestureRecognizer` it's quite overhead. For that purposes `UITableViewDelegate` has own method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Second, you're using self-sizing cell, because of

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 75
```

There is one important rule for that: you should pin `myLabel` to each side of superview (see [official docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/creating_self_sizing_table_view_cells) why):

[image]

Last step, when the `numberOfLines` changed, you should animate `cell`'s height (expand or collapse) without reloading the cell:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
```

[Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614908-beginupdates):

> You can also use this method followed by the endUpdates() method to animate the change in the row heights without reloading the cell.

---

Full code:

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
}

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let cellID = "cell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 75
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 12
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "section " + String(section)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: self.cellID, for: indexPath) as! MyCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none // remove if you need cell selection

        if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
            cell.myLabel?.numberOfLines = 1
            cell.myLabel.text = "This is some long text that should be truncated.  It should not span over multiple lines. Let's hope this actually works. \(indexPath.row)"
        } else {
            cell.myLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
            cell.myLabel.text = "This is some really, really long text.  It should span over multiple lines. Let's hope this actually works. \(indexPath.row)"
        }

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)

        guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MyCell else { return }

        cell.myLabel.numberOfLines = cell.myLabel.numberOfLines == 0 ? 1 : 0

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do two things.

1. Set the **Vertical Content hugging priority** and 
   **Vertical Content compression resistance priority** of the Label to 1000.
2. After changing the number of lines of the Label call the **tableView.beginUpdates()** and **tableView.endUpdates()**

This should work definitely.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
if label.numberOfLines == 0 {
    label.numberOfLines = 1
} else {
    label.numberOfLines = 0
}
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was (Nov. 2023, Xcode 15, iOS 17) unable to make my cells expand with either of these answers. When changing the cell constraints and internal views, the cell would do all sorts of behaviors but expand/collapse.

It all started to work when I changed the `TableView IBOutlet` **Style** from `.insetGrouped` to `.grouped`, and it started working when I set this:

```
self.actionView?.isHidden = self.isCollapsed
self.cellHeightConstraint?.constant = self.isCollapsed ? 50 : 100

self.updateConstraints()
self.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()

self.tableView?.beginUpdates()
self.tableView?.endUpdates()
```

While this `.tableView` property is accessible to the cell via

```
extension UITableViewCell {
    var tableView: UITableView? {
        return superview as? UITableView
    }
}
```

**TLDR:** If you're struggling with changing the cell size for apparent no reason, make sure the TableView Style is not set to `.insetGrouped`.

Edit: typo.